# Visualize a difference equation with Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, visualization, recurrence-relations

I have a difference equation for a Single Pole Infinite Impulse Response Filter, defined on a discrete time-series:

$y[n]-(1-\alpha)*y[n-1]=\alpha*x_n$

While the []s brackets refer to a position n within the series. I'm looking for a visual way to represent this in order to get how this equation behaves. I have tried wolfram-alpha, MalLab... Is anyone me a pointer how I can make MatLab (e.g.) show me the plot for this function? Use-case is a DC offset filter, that uses this SPIIR filter with $\alpha=0,0004$. So it's mostly DSP related.

Best,
Marius

Comment: This looks like an [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).

Comment: Also, this might be more appropriate for our [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a quick rewrite into more 'mathematical' notation:

$$y_n = \alpha x_n + (1-\alpha) y_{n-1}$$

By repeated substitution you can see that this is equal to:

$$
\begin{align}
y_n & = \alpha \left( x_n + (1-\alpha) x_{n-1} + (1-\alpha)^2 x_{n-2} + \cdots \right) \\
& = \alpha \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-\alpha)^k x_{n-k}
\end{align}$$

So $y$ is an infinite sum of past values of $x$ (which is why it's called an *infinite* impulse response filter). One way to visualize this is to look at the weights

$$w_k = \alpha(1-\alpha)^k$$

as a function of $k$, which you can achieve in Matlab by

```
alpha = 0.2;
k = 0:20;
w = alpha .* (1-alpha).^k;
bar(k,w)
```

another way is to generate some data `x` and calculate `y` from it, and compare the two:

```
x = randn(30,1);
y = zeros(30,1);

y(1) = x(1);

for k = 2:30
  y(k) = alpha * x(k) + (1-alpha) * y(k-1);
end

plot(1:30, [x y])
legend({'x','y'})
```

Is this what you meant by 'visualize' the equation?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks! - However the last plot command seems to be wrong: "Error using horzcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: That's because Matlab has an annoying quirk of growing arrays horizontally instead of vertically. It's fixed now.